# Codeigniter: Display an image stored in DB

Tags: image, codeigniter

How do I get an image stored in a field of my database, and put it into a variable for using it in an email message like a signature?

Here is my code:

```
//Model user_model

function getImage(){
  $this->db->select("image");
  $this->db->where("$id", user_id);
  $query = $this->db->get("users");

    if($query->num_rows()>0){
      return result();
    }else{
      return false;
    }  

}

//Controller user_controller

  function image(){
    this->load->model("user_model");

    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');

    $image = $this->user_model->getImage($id);

    echo $image;
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Comment: edited complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example

Model user_model

```
// Pass the id function 

function getImage($id){
    $this->db->where($id, 'user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get("users");

    if($query->num_rows()>0){
      return $query->row_array();
    }else{
      return false;
    }  

}
```

Controller user_controller

```
function image(){
  $this->load->model("user_model");

  $somedata = $this->user_model->getImage($this->session->userdata('id'));

  $data['image'] = $somedata['image'];

  $this->load->view('someview', $data);
}
```

On view

```
<?php echo $image;?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i was trying make it work, but when i call $data['image'] in the view i get the error "Undefined variable: data", i'm using <?php echo $data['image']; ?> for make the call, any idea for fix this error? Thank you again!!

Comment: @AlvaroVergara  I have updated it your way incorrect you should read the user guide fully